# Wowza: get thumbnail with 1 out put video file

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

I'm using Wowza for recording a live stream. I want to get a thumbnail of the live stream. I followed this tutorial
http://blog.svnlabs.com/wowza-live-stream-thumbnail-images-with-http-provider/

Then when I record stream, it saved about 4 video file:

```
streamname.mp4,
streamname_160p.mp4,
streamname_320p.mp4,
streamname_source.mp4
```

Is there any way to save only 1 video file "streamname.mp4" but could still get the thumbnail by URL as the above tutorial mentions?
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @cryptic_star: many thank to you for the editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way.
We have to remain at least one of extending file
e.g

```
streamname.mp4,
streamname_160p.mp4,
```